# mysql SELECT many to many GROUP_CONCAT (how to get all records)

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my first question and sorry if my title is not very good and descriptive.

So i have this mysql query on many to many relationship and it is working fine, i get drivers and its units in format that i want.

```
select 
    d.*, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT u.make,'-', u.model) 
from 
    drivers d 
    left join drivers_units dc 
        on d.driver_id = dc.driverId 
    left join units u 
        on dc.unitId = u.unit_id
```

My problem here is i don't get **ALL drivers** i get only drivers that have at least one unit i understand why (because that driver don't exist in driver_units table), my question here is:

What is best way to get all drivers (with and without any units), can i do it in one query (return all drivers no mater if they have units or not) or i must create new query to select drivers without units ?

I would appreciate mysql query example.

Comment: pls also give sample data and desired output.. it may help us to give you exact solution

Comment: I think, the problem is the `DISTINCT` in your group_concat. That filters the entries. Maybe you have a fiddle?

Comment: It is working without DISTINCT, there is answer below, thank you anyway for answer, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your query, because you have an aggregation function (`group_concat()`) but no `group by`.  Your query should be returning only one row.

To get *all* drivers, use the proper aggregation:

```
select d.*, 
       group_concat(distinct u.make,'-', u.model) 
from drivers d left join
     drivers_units dc 
     on d.driver_id = dc.driverId left join
     units u 
     on dc.unitId = u.unit_id
group by d.driver_id;
```

I am guessing that the `distinct` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is working perfectly. I also removed distinct.